# What happened to the arrow to vote a comment?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-voting

I was voting two comments, and when I was voting the second one, the arrow to vote it vanished.

- I voted the first comment
- I voted the second comment, but I did it too fast
- I clicked on the dialog box saying I have to vote a comment every 5 seconds
- I tried again to vote, but I forgot the counter has been reset; the dialog box still reminds me of the 5 seconds limit
- I tried once again, but 5 seconds were not passed
- I don't see any more the number of votes the comment already received, and the arrow is replaced with a link

  [image: screenshot]

I also tried with the first comment on this very question: I clicked the arrow to vote it, and without to wait 5 seconds, I clicked the arrow again. The result is the following one:

[image: screenshot]

If I click on the "upvote" link, what I get is the following:

[image: screenshot]

The votes, including mine, were two; where is now the other vote?

What happened?
If this makes any difference, I am using Safari 5.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

When I look at the Safari's "Activity" window, I notice the following events:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Repro with FF7 (partly): Upvoting a comment and immediately clicking the (now bold) arrow again makes it disappear.

Comment: I've had this and similar errors a number of times in the past few days. FF8 beta.

Comment: Repro with Chrome as well.

Comment: Posting a comment to work towards my Pundit badge.  Feel free to experiment with this bug using the arrow to the left.

Comment: Should I tag this question as [tag:bug]?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I think you should.  This is definitely *a reproducible problem on the site that you [I] believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error.*  I went ahead and edited it, roll back if you don't want it.    Also, make sure to use `[meta-tag:bug]` instead of `[tag:bug]` when you're referring to tags on MSO, they point to the Stackoverflow tag otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce everything you and [Kevin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110435/what-happened-to-the-arrow-to-vote-a-comment/110444#110444) describe, but some of it. Should be all fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 12):

You stopped too early! The fun hasn't stopped yet!!

There are actually 5 steps in the process:

1. Initial state with darkened arrow and previous number (if any) on hover

   [image]
2. The standard number + darkened arrow after clicking "upvote".

   [image]
3. Click the darkened arrow again (I did this all with one post, you had more comments involved).  Did you get the "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds" notification?

   - Yes, you get the number + upvote link

     [image]
   - No, GOTO 6
4. Click the upvote link for removed numbers and a darkened arrow where the numbers used to be

   [image]
5. Click the darkened arrow for an upvote link and still no numbers

   [image]
6. Click the upvote link for a darkened arrow and still no numbers.  GOTO 5

   [image]